# How to find driver for hard drive (Model: Samsung ST500LM012 HN-M500MBB)

Tags: hard-drive, drivers

Windows 10 has decided to use a generic driver for this hard drive. Unfortunately, I am unable to find where to get a driver. Maybe it's just an old drive that doesn't have a Win10 driver, but I can't even find where to find older drivers.

The problem is that the speed is only a fraction of what it should be so the computer works at a crawl. Based on posts from others I've found on the internet I'm fairly certain it's a driver issue. Just wondering if there's anything I can do about it if Samsung doesn't offer the driver on their website (or is there some secret part of their website I'm missing?)

Comment: hard drives do not have drivers

Comment: Well there is a place you can view the device driver and click to update it... so you can imagine why I would think there was.

Comment: Vendor does not supply drivers for SATA drives because hard drives themselves do not require specific device drivers. Operating systems such as Windows XP/2000 may not automatically recognize the SATA controller in the system. This is especially true if the hardware is newer than the operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This drive is a standard SATA hard drive, meaning it does not require drivers except those bundled with the OS. (Yes, I'm sure).

If its working at a crawl it is dying, and you should back it up and replace the drive ASAP.  (Like don't use it to do anything except that, and count yourself lucky if you don't loose important data).

If you don't believe me, you may be able to see what it thinks of itself by looking at its S.M.A.R.T attributes (you may need to download some free software to do this - smartmontools and crystaldiskinfo are commonly mentioned as doing just this. )

Comment: I am fixing for a friend. I thought same as you and replaced their original drive with this one but same problem is present (I imaged the old and put on the new). I found a few posts of others having same issue after a particular Windows update. Something isn't right, but I believe both hard drives are fine.

Comment: One guy said he found a newer driver for his drive and that fixed it... so I was hoping it would be a similar issue for me. Another said that he was able to roll back and that fixed his issue... that's not an option for me though.

Comment: Could the problem be a partition alignment issue or a faulty SATA port?

Comment: Alternatively could it be the controller is set incorrectly in the motherboard?  Also, is a firmware upgrade available for the motherboard)   I wonder if the drivers you/your friend are looking for are actually SATA drivers for your motherboard rather then your hard drive?

Comment: I used Macrium Reflect to image the original drive and put it on another and it had the same problem. It was marginally faster, just because it was a faster drive, but winsat tests showed random access speeds of barely over 1MB/s. I don't know if that answers your question about whether it's a partition alignment? I assume that's a hardware issue that wouldn't be copied over so I'm guessing that's probably not it.

Comment: On whether it's an issue with the port... will find out soon. I ordered a new SSD drive. If it runs slow too then I will look into that... but what could I do about that on a laptop? Would I pretty much need to get a new motherboard or is that a replaceable part?

Comment: I did a bios update I found for the service tag at dell. Don't know if that's same as firmware? I will check.

Comment: As far as SATA drivers for the motherboard... what am I looking at when I view the driver details for the Disk Drive entry in the Device Manager. Is that what you are calling the SATA driver for the motherboard or are you referring to something else?

Comment: What is the Dell Service Tag?

Comment: Service tag is JH915C2. I put the SSD drive in today and it works great... no issue with it only working at a fraction of it's full speed like with other 2 drives. This suggests to me it's a problem with Windows 10 drivers for those other 2 drives (or SATA drivers for motherboard or whatever).

Comment: Have you tried https://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER03163819M/1/Chipset_Driver_4994F_WN32_10.1.1.7_A00.EXE (This is the Intel chipset driver from Dell for your laptop and probably includes the appropriate driver for the SATA ports)

Comment: Hmm... yeah I wonder if that would have helped. I did in fact go to Dell and used their detection tool, but it did not recommend anything related. I checked also under the Serial ATA category but as I'm sure you know that didn't help. I didn't think to try the Chipset category at the time... but perhaps that could have fixed the issue. I'm somewhat curious to find out... don't know if I'm curious enough to switch the hard drives back or not though. This is one of those stupid laptops where a single cable is fed through the hand rest so that you *have* to disconnect the keyboard. So annoying.

Comment: Its a bit of a long shot - that driver is 3 years old.  If you are going to stick with an SSD, I wouldn't bother!

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. This is for my best friend's mom who occasionally babysits my kid for free, and I've got another kid coming in November so I figure buying her a $60 hard drive was the least I could do :) Thanks for your efforts.